# Selenium Intellij not running the Testng's Test

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have selenium grid setup and coded selenium testng but it does not launch the browser in foreground. What could be the error?

Below are my configurations:

```
clean test -Dproperty=sit-config.properties

<plugin>      
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>GenericTestManager.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


 @Test(groups= {"Login"}, description="Chrome - Login", dataProvider = "loginCredentials")
 @JSErrorsCollectorTestNG(assertJSErrors = true)
 public void test() {
        myChromeDriver.getDriver().navigate().to("www.facebook.com");
 }
```

Please help.

A billion thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Which other application occupies the foreground?

Comment: This is a selenium testng application only created with Intellij IDE.

Comment: For debugging you can use . Add some debug point & use in command line  -Dmaven.surefire.debug  https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html

Comment: Also in surefire add -                     <include>**/GenericTestManager.java</include>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rename the GenericTestMnaager to Tests.java and it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the protocol i.e. `https` while invoking `navigate().to()` as follows:

```
myChromeDriver.getDriver().navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

Comment: The problem is lyies on the surefire plugin does not pick up my test GenericTestManager.java. How to troubleshoot?